# $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ principal ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I see a question:

> Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is principal ring and $\mathbb{Z}_{n} \implies \langle l \rangle,$ $l$ divides $n$.

My proof: Let $I$ a ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. Then, exists $d \in I$ least congruence class. Take any $m \in I$, by division algoritm, $m = dq+r$ for $0 \leq r < d$, so $m-qd \in I$. Therefore $r \equiv 0$ and $m=qd.$ That is, $I= \langle d \rangle.$ Why $d$ divides $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: an ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is also an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and hence contains $0=n$. Take $d$ to be the smallest element of $I$ and get a contradiction from division algorithm as you did.